# How to create an inteface either in C# or VB with C++ Logic

Tags: c#, c++, dll, c++-cli

My question is what's the best way to create an inteface with C++ code.

Basically so far I have a console project in c++, that works as I expect to, but I now want to make a GUI for it. The choices to me seemed to be:

1. Make a dll of the c++ project, and then make a C# form which uses the dll to do the logic.
2. Same as 1 except with VB.
3. Use QT or something eqvilent and make the inteface in the same project.

I've been trying option 1 for quite sometime. I made the library I believe successfully by making a library project in Visual Studio 2005. I then put it in my c# project but I then had a problem of being able to instantuate my class, but the c# project couldn't see my methods.

The only fix I could find to this was to use the ref keyword. The problem with this was then not being able to mix managed and unmanaged code and trying this on one of the larger classes produced about 250 errors.

Option 2 i had the same problem with.

I'll start option 3 if I have to, I just wondered if I was missing anything fundamental or any suggestions in general?

Cheers for reading.

Comment: If you want to stick with option 1, ask a new question and post some code and the errors you are getting. There are a lot of smart people here that have worked with managed and unmanaged code and can help you. As far as what framework to use? Pick what works best for your environment. Don't pick one just because you can't get the others to work...

Comment: Is your C++ managed code, or unmanaged?

Comment: My C++ code is mostly unmanged. It requires some form of garbage collection, I'd like to post some code but I'm not on the correct machine. But an example i was having was trying to declare a char array without initialising it. the compiler would complain that I was trying to mix unmanaged code into managed code. The main problem really is the fact that I'm adapting code from another program so it's about 15 classes big and it may be a lot of work to adapt 15 classes of code to get it working compared to just making some sort of GUI on QT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can use C++ code from C#, but if it's unmanaged C++ code, you have to delve into the realm of pinvoke to call your code.

If you're attempting to leverage an existing C++ library from .NET, one of the easiest ways to do this is by using C++/CLI as a wrapper around your unmanaged library. C++/CLI compiles into .NET bytecode, but features lots of automatic unmanaged interop. A phrase that's often floated about when using C++/CLI unmanaged interop is "it just works". It's an accurate phrase.

Once you have a C++/CLI wrapper for your unmanaged code, C# should be able to see everything exposed by your C++/CLI library.

Comment: is the above a good tutorial on the subject? Will i have to unwrap every bit of unmanaged code?

Comment: Yes, you should wrap all unmanaged code and unwrap any managed parameters you get from managed code. The tutorial you linked is very old and probably not directly relevant today. It's actually Managed C++, not C++/CLI -- in 2005 there was a language syntax rewrite that resulted in C++/CLI.

Comment: *... if it's unmanaged C++ code, you have to delve into the realm of pinvoke to call your code.* - Unless it is a COM component, in which case you can simply add it as a reference.

Comment: so a reference being with the ref keyword? Can i ref specific methods or just classes?